# This document is copyright

Tags: word-usage

I frequently come across this expression in technical writing:

```
This document is copyright (c) 2012 XYZ Company Inc.
```

Is that a correct/acceptable way to express it? "This document is copyright..." sounds very weird to me.

Do the copyright laws of the UK or US perhaps mandate or necessitate a wording such as this?

**EDIT**

It has been suggested to close this question because it is a legal question, not a usage question. So I feel I need to clarify:

This is meant to be a question about English usage. The core of my question is the words, "Is that a correct/acceptable way to express it?", by which I mean "correct and acceptable English usage." My last sentence is merely meant as a possible guess as to the reason for a possibly strange usage.

Comment: Hello, oz1cz. Can you explain exactly why it sounds so weird? More importantly, have you checked in say a dictionary whether there are examples of 'copyright' used as a predicative adjective?

Comment: It is more correct to say 'this document has been copyrighted', I would say.

Comment: What seems a bit weird (to me) is the year and company name that follow the adjective “copyright”.   @EdwinAshworth

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Merriam Webster does give the meaning, "not allowed to be copied without permission from the author". However, as jc correctly states, following it by a year and an company still makes it weird.

Comment: It's not at the sentence level.  It's in a format quite similar to many references in articles, films etc. As to whether the exact format is a legal requirement, that's off-topic on ELU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not one of EL & U. As such any answer would depend on the legal juristriction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Are there other examples of an adjective being modified by a noun (or more nouns) that follows it?

Comment: @jc This is arguably not running text, and grading into a labelling, where the words may be arranged as a display. 'Top secret ... 2012 ...  Ministry of Disinformation' etc and 'Passed 07' (on a transistor radio, say) might be seen as closer relatives.

Comment: @David, my intention was to ask a question about English usage. And my words "Is that a correct/acceptable way to express it?" is intended to reflect that desire. The last sentence is meant to be a possible guess as to the reason for a possibly strange usage. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Look up the word in good dictionary and let us know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can start a campaign in support of "has been copyrighted" if you like.  But I think it has already been lost.

[image]

[LINK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20copyright%2Chas%20been%20copyrighted&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20copyright%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20copyrighted%3B%2Cc0)

Perhaps the graphs suggest something caused this wording to increase around 1940?

Comment: That's a very interesting graph, @GEdgar. Thank you. You're right; it's probably a lost cause.

Comment: You didn't look at the hits.  Very few match the OP's context.